# Case insensitive searching for a string in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, search, case-insensitive

I am iterating over each text node, and looking for a search string whether it is available in that text node or not. If it's present I will wrap around the span node to do the highlighting. The sample code is available at this link: .http://jsfiddle.net/LcRDz/.

Right now if a user gives a word, it will search only that word.
I need to search the DOM for the words irrespective of case. For example if my search word is `the`, it should highlight the words `The, THE, the`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the check with `indexOf` use `toLowercase` on both values, making the comparison case insensitive.

```
 //Notice both n.nodeValue and word are sent to lowercase.
 for (var i;
        (i = n.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase(), i)) > -1; 
           n = after) {
             var after = n.splitText(i + word.length);
             var highlighted = n.splitText(i);
             var span = document.createElement('span');
             span.className = "spanClass";
             span.style.backgroundColor = "red";
             span.appendChild(highlighted);
             after.parentNode.insertBefore(span, after);
         }
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/LcRDz/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should solve just by modifing

```
for (var i;
    (i = n.nodeValue.indexOf(word, i)) > -1; n = after)
```

with

```
for (var i;
    (i = n.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase(), i)) > -1; n = after)
```

Comment: `word` should also be sent to lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop in highlightWords method from

Original:

```
for (var i;
             (i = n.nodeValue.indexOf(word, i)) > -1; n = after)
```

New:

```
for (var i;
             (i = n.nodeValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase(), i)) > -1; n = after)
```